# Run windows executable from web

Tags: php, python, node.js, windows, server

**I would like to know if its possible to run a windows application from web and if there are some guides to help me on the process.**

***Scenario :***

- I have a windows application that is hosted on server#1 .
- There are multiple servers running the same application .
- The application has multiple input boxes and a submit button .
- From a web application ( php maybe ) that has the same input boxes I
  would like to send the command to the server to run into the
  application .

---

After my searches I found out that I can do this using **NodeJS + Python + PHP** , but cannot find a good point from where I can get started.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it can be as simple (and extraodinarily stupid/insecure/horribly bad) as doing `<?php exec('path/to/program.exe ' . $_POST['hack_my_system_please'])`

Comment: I think you've missed `NodeJS + Python + PHP + GO + .Net + Ruby + ...` Start form learning about web tech